VSCode rollback to 1.70 when update
I have been using VSCode version 1.86 all along, and when I upgraded last week, the version automatically reverts back to version 1.70.
enter image description here
When I click upgrade again, it prompts that there are no available versions.
I have tried upgrading from 1.86 twice, but both times I have rolled back to version 1.70.
May I ask what could be causing this?
